# How do I reactivate terminal in VS Code?

Tags: javascript, visual-studio-code, terminal

I am very new to coding and following a tutorial at the moment (building a simple CRUD app). The issue is that once I run the command "nodemon app", I can no longer use any other commands. I can type it out but hitting enter does nothing. How do I use other commands without opening a new terminal?
[click here for image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/35Xen.png)

Comment: The nodemon command will run until you stop it. To stop a command type Ctrl+C (the control key and the c key together)

Comment: This question kinda belongs on superuser, not stackoverflow.

Comment: You mean you want to command on terminal by entering `nodemon app`?

Answer (score 1):

Ctrl+C will interrupt the running process in a terminal, in this case, killing `nodemon`.

That would allow you to run other commands, but will lose you your `nodemon` process.

Another option (that might be more suitable for VSCode) is to open a second terminal (Ctrl+Shift+`, or Ctrl+Shift+5 to open side-by-side). In the second terminal, you can then execute whatever other commands you want.

Alternatively, you can append the `&` character to a command to have it run in the background. This would allow you to run something like `nodemon app &` and then run other commands, but be aware that in this arrangement, the output of the commands will become interleaved - so if the `node` application is writing to the console and the other command also outputs information, they might become tricky to read.